# Limiting the number of clang++.exe instances running during a build

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

While building my android project, cmake runs several instances of `clang++.exe` that eat up my machine's resources. Is there a way to limit this? Would such a solution lead to longer build times?

Here is a screenshot of my resource map: [resource status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8bV.png)

I have the following package versions:

android studio: 4.0.1

ndk: 21.3.6528147

cmake:3.10.2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557585/limit-cpu-cores-for-ndkbuild-with-cmake-and-ninja/

Comment: I did go through the thread, however the most-voted solution requires a minimum cmake v3.11, which is something I would like to avoid for now.

Comment: I updated my cmake to v3.11 and tried out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567570/14022225) as highlighted by @michael, I am still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot indicates you are generating for the Ninja build system... so...
If building through the CMake executable, [documented here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html), you would use:

```
cmake --build . -- -j 8
```

which would build with up to 8 CPUs in parallel.  (Change 8 to however many instances you'd like.)

If just building using Ninja directly, you would use something like:

```
ninja -j 8
```

to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is there a way to do this via the `externalNativeBuild{ cmake {...}}` environment?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way via `externalNativeBuild`, though I'm not too familiar with development on Android.
There may be a way, externally, with some `Ninja` configuration related to [Pools](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#ref_pool)?